# NETTY 4 DefaultEventExecutorGroup seems to be blocking IO?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, nio

I noticed that when I add a little bit of latency onto one of my handlers (supposed to be executed by the DefaultEventExecutorGroup) that it causes the user to experience timeouts on their end? Without the latency everything seems to be running fine, but 1ms of latency shouldn't cause 1/3 of my users to timeout. My current load is around 20k requests per second, not necessarily all concurrent.

Here is my pipeline setup

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
    p.addLast("frameDecoder", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(80));
    p.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    p.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    p.addLast(CoolServer.getExecutors(), "cool_request", new CoolServerHandler()); 

    //private static CoolServer.executors = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(48);
    //CoolServer.getExecutors() returns CoolServer.executors 
}
```

Here is how my CoolServerHandler is setup: ("extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler/")

```
public class CoolServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>{
//default constructor used
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

    //LOOP TO ADD SOME LATENCY TO MY HANDLER 
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeIncrement = 1; // waits for this many milliseconds
    for (long checkTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); checkTime  < (currentTime + timeIncrement); checkTime = System.currentTimeMillis()){
        //busy waiting
    } 
    //encodeResponse taken out for simplicity, simple string manipulation function
    String response = encodeResponse(key, true);

    ReferenceCountUtil.retain(msg);
    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.flush();
}



@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {           
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

I have tried to keep the code simple in order to prevent this post from being too long, let me know if more information is needed. Thank You

Comment: how many cores of your test sever? And what is your timeout setting?